# Main Handle Of A Window

Tags: autoit

Just trying to use ControlSend but the program is still reluctant. Now I found out the Main Handle but I still don't know how to write it correctly. Helps getting appreciated.

```
;   Process: System.Diagnostics.Process (javaw)
;   Process ID: 4752
;   Handle Count: 430
;   Responding: Yes
;   Title: ?ok???O?
;                                               <= Looks stange but this is the title.
;   ?
;   Main Handle: 1115426


$mainHanlde = ""

While 1
   ControlClick("", "", $mainHanlde,"{Down}")
   Sleep(900)
   ControlClick("", "", $mainHanlde,"{Down}")
   Sleep(900)
   ControlClick("", "", $mainHanlde,"{Down}")
   Sleep(900)
   ControlClick("", "", $mainHanlde,"a")
   Sleep(Random(750, 2000, 1))
   ControlClick("", "", $mainHanlde,"a")
   Sleep(Random(750, 2000, 1))
   ControlClick("", "", $mainHanlde,"a")
   Sleep(Random(750, 2000, 1))
   ControlClick("", "", $mainHanlde,"a")
   Sleep(3000)
WEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need the handle. You can get it with `$handle = WinGetHandle("[ACTIVE]")` after a Sleep(999) while you click on the application. Be aware that the handle can change with each program run.

Then you try to confirm it with `WinFlash($handle)`. Or write the result of WinGetTitle(...) to your console.

And at last you use it with the Control-Functions.... `ControlSend($handle, Default, "", "{Down}")`.

These three simple steps help me with my applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the title and text and leave the id blank. That should work.